# How to prevent disappearing text within eclipse sourceviewer with SingleLineRule?

Tags: eclipse

I'm having a problem with SourceViewer in Eclipse. Big text within rule-affected part disappears.
Did anyone encounter a similar issue or knows what needs to change for it to not disappear?

I used org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer and org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.SingleLineRule.

I'm working on a custom Javascript editor and have setup 2 rules for special formatting of text: one for text surrounded with "'" and one surrounded with """. Now I input a really long text into a single line (over 100k characters), which is a valid JSON surrounded with "'". The issue is that the JSON part disapears. I can still edit it, and if I remove one of the surrounding "'", the text pops up. However, if there are no """ in said text (just really long text surrounded with "'"), the text will not reappear. From that I concluded that it needs to be some kind of rule issue.